# Should I use hashes or ActiveRecord::Relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm really lacking some knowledge regarding efficiency/performance when working with massive amount of data.

I need to do some calculations on different models and then updating them. I was thinking:

Step I. Get the data from each table in hashes (hash_table_1, hash_table_2 etc) "plucking" the active record relations and then map it in a hash

Step II. Do calculations and change the values in the hashes (iterate over hashes, searching ids in hashes); doing them directly in sql is a big NO-NO, since I have instructions not do it, I'm contemplating If I should do them on active records and then update, but I will have to update a lot of them.

Step III. Updating data with Table_1.update(hash_table_1), Table_2.update(hash_table_2) etc. OR use raw SQL to update

Should I be using ActiveRecord::Relations instead of hashes? Are they more memory efficient?

Comment: What do these calculations look like? The most efficient approach would almost certainly be doing it all in SQL inside the database and leaving Ruby, Rails, and ActiveRecord out of it completely.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for your interest. Doing them directly in SQL is a big NO-NO since I have instructions not to do calculations directly in SQL. My instructions are: find data, calculate, update

Comment: Wow. Any chance that you can convince the person with the instructions to be reasonable? Do they have any reasons for doing it this way? Misguided notions of portability or "The Rails Way" perhaps? Letting the database do what it does (i.e. manage large volumes of data) is almost certainly going to be the most efficient approach.

Comment: @muistooshort no chance, since find, calculate, update need to be separate

Comment: I guess the best is to do the tests by yourself. But loading massive amount of data on your server may just be impossible. How many records do you have to make calculations on ? I have attended AWS conference in Paris and eventhough I was the noobest of all attendees on some workshop, they did insightful tests with different big data technologies. But all tests were done via SQL on AWS hosted databases. Loading big samples was not even mentionned. (of course if the servers are in-house, I guess anything can be possible) (but if you are on Heroku, I bet you have to rely on SQL)

Comment: Actualy if your database is hundred millions of records, I think this is not a Ruby question. You should replicate your DB on a local machine and find the right tool to query it in a timely fashion.